# Login Page testing in Jmeter in php website

Tags: jmeter

I am testing an website's login form using jmeter , website is created on cake php.

The Request header of POST method was

```
CakeCookie[username]=Q2FrZQ==.4hQpPE8O4tl+iBRWfrgElBgbwJKK6Q==; CakeCookie[password]=Q2FrZQ==.skRyYRRZ; CAKEPHP=avdhr3i8abe04nq74ra5k596f3
```

While the html description of login page was as follows :

```
<input name="data[Salon][username]" class="span4" id="username" placeholder="Username or Email" type="text" **>

<input name="data[Salon][password]" class="span4" id="password" placeholder="Required" type="password"**>
```

My Sampler contains the following:

{Please note that I am getting variable by Global declaration in Test plan}

```
username = ${username}
password = ${password}
Cookie = ${Cookie_Cakephp}
```

but I am getting the error on response :

```
Wrong username or password
```

please guide what should be done to solve the scenario.

Please correct me if I am wrong : "Every time we have take reference of id of the html control to pass value ? example if the textbox id is `username` we have pass the value using

```
username = ${variable name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass direct actual user name and password instead of through variable.